# can't call a static method from Model(PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

```
$page = new \App\Page::where('page', $pageName)->first();
```

it gives me an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'where' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'
```

can someone tell me what is wrong with the first line of code?

Comment: What does the `where` method look like or what framework is this?

Comment: @nerdlyist its laravel, in the docs is the same

Comment: Can you include ~15 lines above this line

Comment: @ʰᵈˑtheres no other code just this

Comment: Then how is `$pageName` defined? We need some context.

Comment: oh great downvotes

Comment: @ʰᵈˑeverything is defined, its just a syntax problem, not logic

Comment: Use the tags better then to get more help

Comment: `new` can not used with calling a method togehter! You can do this on a instance `print (new ABC())->show();` but this will not work with a static method! For static method just do `$page = \App\Page::where('page', $pageName)->first();`

Comment: You don't need `new` here

Comment: Fyi static methods don't need the `new`.

Comment: now I see......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order of the operations. If you want to generate a new object, you should do that first and then call the static method on that:

```
$page = (new \App\Page)::where('page', $pageName)->first();
        ^             ^
```

(not very useful as you don't use the object after that...)

If you don't want to create a new object, you can call the method directly:

```
$page = \App\Page::where('page', $pageName)->first();
```

Comment: great answer, thanks, I've missed this "new" keyword

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel, this should look like :

```
$page = Page::all()->where('page', '=', $pageName)->first();
```